# Mysterious logout

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, logout

I'm on Linux, I'm using a Red Hat 6.6 workstation. Every now and then (usually once, sometimes twice a day) I get a user logout. Or something that looks like a user logout: the screen goes black for 1 second and the next thing I'll see is the login screen, everything I worked on and I didn't save is lost.

The only thing I'm sure of is that I don't log out myself. I'm not sure if it's a system error, I'm not sure if another user logs in and kicks me out (I find this one unlikely as this is a workstation, not a server), I'm not sure if some automatic process runs in the background that has this side-effect.

While I'm somewhat familiar with Linux environments, I don't have deep knowledge of the system. How could I check what causes my problem? What logs should I look into, what should I look for?

Comment: As to other users logging in: That should not kick you out. Instead you would have two people logged in at the same time (akin to windows terminal server setups).

Comment: Yes, the fact that another user logs in should not kick me out. The other user may though. Manually.

Comment: You use `last`to see when a user last logged in. (Just in case you have a prankster as a coworker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of *Catch 22* situation. If you are root, you can inspect the log files, but then no one else can have kicked you out. But if you are not root and someone can have kicked you out, you cannot inspect the log files.

At any rate, the log file to inspect is */var/log/auth.log*, which will show who, if anyone, was logged in as root at the time of your kick-out.

The following command

```
  grep -nrI "session closed for user YourName" /var/log
```

will provide a list of your disconnections, comprehensive of exact times and dates, which you can cross-relate with the presence/absence of every user on your system.

You may also inspect system log files like */var/log/dmesg* and */var/log/syslog* for events occurring around the time of your disconnections, to see whether your are dealing with bugs rather than mischief.

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot you said RedHat.

Red Hat family distributions (including CentOS and Fedora) use /var/log/messages and /var/log/secure where Debian-family distributions use /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth.log.

Comment: `sudo` rights to the rescue. :) However, my system doesn't seem to have either `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/syslog*` files.

Comment: @ytg Please see my edit.